# Why creating a custom hook always triggers re-renderings and using useDispatch and useSelector directly do not?

Tags: reactjs, redux

There is a pattern I was using on a project where most of the state resides on redux. I also try to keep the application logic close to redux, so I use selectors and I wrap all the possible actions to be taken into custom hooks.

Running some profiling tests I noticed that, when I use my custom hooks (example below) all the components that use them re-render when the redux state changes:

```
export const useDefinitionForm = () => {
  const { description, step } = useAppSelector((state) => {
    const { name, color, icon, duration } = state.descriptionForm;
    return { description: { name, color, icon, duration }, step: state.descriptionForm.step };
  });

  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();

  return { description, step, actions: bindActionCreators(actions, dispatch) };
};
```

However, when I use the useDispatch and useSelector hooks directly on the target component, then those components only re-render when the specific redux section changes:

```
const DurationSection = () => {
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();
  const duration = useAppSelector((state) => state.descriptionForm.duration);
  return (
    <Section title="Expected duration" hint={duration} step="duration">
      <Typography variant="subtitle1">How much will this task usually last?</Typography>
      <DurationSlider
        value={duration}
        onChange={(value) => dispatch(setDuration(value))}
        valueLabelDisplay="on"
      />
    </Section>
  );
};
```

Why is this? How can I change the custom hooks so they are as performant as using the hooks directly on the component? I try to keep the components as dumb as possible.

Comment: You are listening to changes of `name`, `color` and `icon` also in the first one. so the updates are due to these three state properties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The selector in your custom hook returns a new object every time:

```
export const useDefinitionForm = () => {
  const { description, step } = useAppSelector((state) => {
    const { name, color, icon, duration } = state.descriptionForm;
    return { description: { name, color, icon, duration }, step: state.descriptionForm.step };
  });

  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();
  //you are returning a new object here every time
  return { description, step, actions: bindActionCreators(actions, dispatch) };
};
```

The selector in your other example does not:

```
const duration = useAppSelector(
  (state) => 
    //you are only returning a value from state here
    state.descriptionForm.duration
);
```

All functions you pass to useSelecor will be executed every time the state changed and if that function returns a changed value your component will re render.

You can use reselect to memoize the result of previous selectors and only return a new object if any of the re used selector(s) return a changed value:

```
const selectDescriptionForm = state => state.descriptionForm;
//you can create selectors to selectStep, selectDuration, selectIcon ...
//  and use those instead if this still causes needless re renders
const selectDuration = createSelector(
  [selectDescriptionForm],
  //the following function will only be executed if
  //  if selectDescriptionForm returns a changed value
  ({ name, color, icon, duration, step })=>({
    description: { 
      name, color, icon, duration 
    }, step
  })
)
export const useDefinitionForm = () => {
  const { description, step } = useAppSelector(selectDuration);
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();
  //making sure actions is not needlessly re created
  const actions = useMemo(
    ()=>bindActionCreators(actions, dispatch),
    [dispatch]
  )
  return { description, step, actions };
};
```

Here is an updated version selecting each item of description form you need and if any of the items change will re create the component data:

```
const selectDescriptionForm = (state) =>
  state.descriptionForm;
const selectName = createSelector(
  [selectDescriptionForm],
  (descriptionForm) => descriptionForm.name
);
const selectColor = createSelector(
  [selectDescriptionForm],
  (descriptionForm) => descriptionForm.color
);
const selectIcon = createSelector(
  [selectDescriptionForm],
  (descriptionForm) => descriptionForm.icon
);
const selectDuration = createSelector(
  [selectDescriptionForm],
  (descriptionForm) => descriptionForm.duration
);
const selectStep = createSelector(
  [selectDescriptionForm],
  (descriptionForm) => descriptionForm.step
);
const selectCompoentData = createSelector(
  [
    selectName,
    selectColor,
    selectIcon,
    selectDuration,
    selectStep,
  ],
  //the following function will only be executed if
  //  any of the functions in the previous list returns
  //  a changed value
  (name, color, icon, duration, step) => ({
    description: {
      name,
      color,
      icon,
      duration,
    },
    step,
  })
);
export const useDefinitionForm = () => {
  const { description, step } = useAppSelector(
    selectCompoentData
  );
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();
  //making sure actions is not needlessly re created
  const actions = useMemo(
    () => bindActionCreators(actions, dispatch),
    [dispatch]
  );
  return { description, step, actions };
};
```

Comment: Your response makes a lot of sense. However, will not selectDescriptionForm return a different value any time the redux state for descriptionForm gets updated?

Comment: @Danielo515 Yes but when anything else changes it will not. What you can do is create selectors or each item in description form and use that to get the data for your component (see updated answer)